# JAXB does not throw an Error on wrong dateTime values

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an XML schema, where element *Calling1* is defined like this:

```
<xsd:element name="Calling1" type="xsd:dateTime">
```

I have generated Jaxb bindings :

```
 <xjc extension="true" schema="${basedir}/message.xsd"
  destdir="${basedir}/src" package="org.test"/>
```

I am using JAXB to unmarshal XML documents to Java representation. 
If my XML cantains element Calling1, which value is not a correct dateTime, for example

```
<Calling1>NOT_A_DATETIME</Calling1>
```

JAXB does not throw any error, but returns me an java object, which property *calling1* is null.

Why i get null, and not an Error? How can i change that Jaxb behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you set the schema on your `Unmarshaller` by calling `setSchema` ? You will need to specify the xsd file as well as the Schema NS URI for validation to take place